# Displaying Hexadecimal numbers

Tags: c++

We would display Hexadecimals in A03Eh format which A=10 & E=14, and A is a nibble. But I have seen another display like this : 0x002314A8 , How can we convert the above number into this format ? what is this format ?

Comment: I don't quite understand your problem, but checking out the [printf format specifiers](http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/io/c/printf_format) might help you.

Comment: A03Eh is assembler format, 0x0000A03E is C/Unix format, padding to 8 bytes is optional and stems from representing 32-bit memory addresses in output, h and x stands for hexadecimal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The format `0x` is the standard Unix way of representing hexadecimal numbers. I am used to seeing `0x` at the beginning and not `h` at the end.

That is the only difference. Like Péter Török said, if you're using C/C++ there are ways to modify what is shown when you print.

Comment: Which was implicit in every other answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
int a = 0x002314A8;
printf("a = 0x%08X", a);
```

or

```
std::out << "a = 0x" << std::hex << std::uppercase << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(8) << std::setprecision(8) << a ;
```

Answer (score -1):

Write a function that takes an integer and returns a string in that format.  Then call it like this:

```
std::cout << toHex(0xA03E);
```

It shouldn't be that difficult a function to write.  Using the ios::hex manipulator will display your number in the 0x format.  Is that what you wanted?

Comment: writing an extra function for converting to hex may not be necessary, using the `std::hex` will be enough

Comment: @Cesar: Not if he wants to display his number like this "A03Eh"

Comment: @Benjamin Lindley: printf("%Xh", a);